# How do you turn iptables off in Puppet

Tags: puppet

In puppet what is the equivalent of the following command?

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Does there exist a iptables service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the `service` resource:

```
service { 'iptables':
  ensure => 'stopped',
  enable => 'false'
}
```